# In latest git commit a jar file is missing although it has been added in a previous commit - Why?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have an issue with my latest version of my project. I am using bitbucket as a remote server and cloned the project which i pushed at work. I made a feature branch and committed some stuff and in the second to last commit I added a jar file.[image]

[image]

Now when I clone this repository and switch to this branch where the commits were done, the jar file is not there.

In the latest commit there were only changes in some java files, so the previously added jar has not been removed

My question is where is this jar file gone?? I can add it manually thats not the problem but I want to understand what happened and what did I wrong. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Your jar file is empty right? I'm not sure git handles easily empty files.

Comment: Did you track the new JAR file by typing `git add newjar.JAR` _before_ you made the commit with hash `bd80cc8` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this steps,

1. Clone and go to appropriate branch.
2. see whether jar was truly added in your mentioned commit by `git log bd80cc8 --stat`. This will show you all the files which have been added in the commit `bd80cc8`.
3. If jar file is not showing that means you mistakenly forgot to add this in that commit.
4. If file is present in this commit, check with `git bisect`.